# Update button color

Tags: java, android, colors

I have to make an android memory game where a sequence of colors show up on the screen and you then have to click the colors that came up. To display the sequence of colors I'm just using an unclickable button that changes colors. I'm currently doing this using a thread with runOnUiThread but every time it will only change the button to the last color I want it to. Why wont it change to any previous color?

```
    final ArrayList<Integer> colours = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Button buttonOne = (Button) findViewById(R.id.colourOne);
    Button buttonTwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.colourTwo);
    Button buttonThree = (Button) findViewById(R.id.colourThree);
    Button buttonFour = (Button) findViewById(R.id.colourFour);

    ColorDrawable buttonOneColor = (ColorDrawable) buttonOne.getBackground();
    ColorDrawable buttonTwoColor = (ColorDrawable) buttonTwo.getBackground();
    ColorDrawable buttonThreeColor = (ColorDrawable) buttonThree.getBackground();
    ColorDrawable buttonFourColor = (ColorDrawable) buttonFour.getBackground();

    int one = buttonOneColor.getColor();
    int two = buttonTwoColor.getColor();
    int three = buttonThreeColor.getColor();
    int four = buttonFourColor.getColor();

    colours.add(one);
    colours.add(two);
    colours.add(three);
    colours.add(four);

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(int x = 0; x < colours.size(); x++) {
                    try {
                        Button light = (Button) findViewById((R.id.light));
                        light.setBackgroundColor(colours.get(x));
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
                }
            }
    });
```

The thread is sleeping after each setBackground color but the buttons color wont actually change until the loop reaches its last loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create a new `Thread` and inside on the Thread call `runOnUiThread` and change the color. Also you have to initialize the button out of the Thread. You must declare variable `x` out of the `onCreate` method

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for(x = 0; x < colours.size(); x++) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            light.setBackgroundColor(colours.get(x));
                        }
                    });
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks a million :) Only 101 more things to do!

Comment: glad it helped! hehe happy coding :D